# How to make a read-only property writeable in a derived class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an enumeration property on a C# base class that I want to be effectively read-only on all derived classes *except one* (on which I need the property to be read-write).

My enumeration is declared like so:

```
enum Visibility { Public, Shared, Private }
```

(the enum member names have nothing to do with C# visibility modifiers, by the way!)

Initially I thought I would be able to declare the property on the base class like so:

```
abstract class DataViewBase
{
    public Visibility Visibility { get; protected set; }
}
```

and then change the declaration on the derived class:

```
sealed class FooDataView : DataViewBase
{
    public Visibility Visibility { get; set; }
}
```

thus making the setter public, but I should have realised that this hides the base **Visibility** property and generates a compiler warning. Adding the `new` keyword (ie. `public new Visibility ...`) gets rid of the warning, but the property on **FooDataView** effectively becomes an entirely new property with no connection to the one on the base class. Hence if I do this:

```
    var foo = new FooDataView();
    foo.Visibility = Visibility.Shared;
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Visibility);  // Shared
    var casted = (DataViewBase) foo;
    Console.WriteLine(casted.Visibility);  // Public
```

the two **Visibility** property values differ, which is not what I want.

I ultimately worked around this by declaring the property like so:

```
sealed class FooDataView : DataViewBase
{
    public new Visibility Visibility
    {
        get { return base.Visibility; }
        set { base.Visibility = value; }
    }
}
```

This ensures that the two **Visibility** properties are kept "in-sync".

However, after having done all this I'm wondering if there's another way of accomplishing what I want (as per the question title), given that my solution seems somewhat inelegant. I can't think of any other obvious solutions.

Comment: "change the declaration on the derived class" - in .NET, this is usually synonymous with declaring "an entirely new" member. You can change the *behaviour* (while maintaining the *interface*) of members by using the `virtual` and `override` keywords, respectively. In your case, however, I would have suggested exactly what you eventually did yourself, have all classes inherit the read-only property, and shadow that property by a writeable property in your one particular class. You may want to add an answer yourself and after a while mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about these two:

**1. Add A New Method**

```
class FooDataView : DataViewBase
{
    public void ChangeVisibility(Visibility visibility)
    {
        Visibility = visibility;
    }
}
```

Just add a new `ChangeVisibility()` method. I think this is the simplest.

**2. Use Interface:**

```
public interface IDataView
{
    Visibility Visibility { get; }
}

public class DataView : IDataView
{
    public Visibility Visibility { get; set; }
}

public class PrivateDataView : IDataView
{
    public Visibility Visibility
    {
        get { return Visibility.Private; }
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer the first approach.

Comment: The first approach makes the most sense I guess. For the user of the class it comes down to the difference between setting a property and calling a method, and I think the former wins out for its simplicity. However, either approach is preferable IMO to anything that requires casting to an interface.

Comment: Yea, I agree. I also prefer the first approach.

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted answer, although in truth any of the answers posted would have worked. I think your first solution (method that changes the visibility) is the easiest to use for the "end user".

Answer (score 1):

> However, after having done all this I'm wondering if there's another
>   way of accomplishing what I want (as per the question title), given
>   that my solution seems somewhat inelegant. I can't think of any other
>   obvious solutions.

No. There is no other solution. Why do you want to change the property to be publicly settable in a derived class (it seems like the setter should also be public in the base class)? Maybe you should expose this functionality in some other way.

Comment: _Why do you want to change the property to be publicly settable in a derived class_: basically it is important that all of my derived types have a Visibility property, as my code generally deals with the base class. However, only one of the derived types should allow the "end user" to change the Visibility; for all other derived types, the Visibility may be different from the base type (hence the _protected_ setter) but is essentially hard-coded and set when the object is created.

Comment: I guess what I could have done was create a public virtual getter/setter in the base class, throwing an exception in the base class setter, but override the getter/setter in the derived class to use its own private backing field. However, I am also serializing these objects and thought the exception in the setter would cause trouble when deserializing.

Answer (score 1):

You may create an Interface that accesses the setter:

```
interface ISetVisibility {
    Visibility Visibilty {set;}
}

class MyDerived : MyBase, ISetVisibility {
    Visibility ISetVisibilty.Visibility { set {/* ... */ } }
}
```

Now within you main-class you may use the following:

```
((ISetVisibility) myDerived).Visibility = Visibilty.Shared;
```

Comment: This does work, and is quite elegant. The only downside I can see, as you illustrate in your code, is that the user of the class must cast to the interface in order to set the property value.

Comment: Also, you may want to edit your answer to remove the `public` access modifiers: they can't be declared on an interface member or when implementing an interface member explicitly.

Comment: @StevenRands Ah thanks, you´re right. I´ve updated the answer appropriately